# Issues with returning an int array in Java

Tags: arrays, function, return-type

I am trying to return an array after reversing(or at least that's what I think I did; not the issue) inside this function but i am getting errors like:

> This method must return a result of type int[]

```
public static int[] arrayLeftRotation(int[] a, int n, int k) 
{   
    int iter = k-1;
    int arr[] = new int[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        if(iter >4)
        {
            iter = 0;
        }
        arr[i] = a[iter];
        iter++;

        return arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: put return outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Well since there is a *missing return statement*. Also, you can avoid a `for` loop if you place a `return` inside it without any specific condition, since that would return after the first iteration itself. So move the return statement out of your `for` loop and it should compile as :

```
public static int[] arrayLeftRotation(int[] a, int n, int k) {   
    int iter = k-1;
    int arr[] = new int[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++) {
        if(iter > 4) {
            iter = 0;
        }
        arr[i] = a[iter];
        iter++;           
    }
    return arr;
}
```